# Making text the div size

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with this css problem. I'm trying to make a list at the left side on the following fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/KH45Y/72/.

```
<div id="left">
    <ul id="myList">
    </ul>
</div>
```

It was good when the items name were short but when I tried long names, they were going over the right div.

How can I make the list items name stay on the left div even if they are going inline ?

Comment: If the item name is too long, what would you like to do with it? Do you want to wrap it onto the next line? Hide it *behind* the `#right` div?

Comment: Yes I'd like to wrap it onto the next line if it's too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KH45Y/75/)

```
word-break: break-all;
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you just put a space in your item name where you'd like the line to break it should do it automatically for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/KH45Y/73/

i.e.

```
var textnode = document.createTextNode("ContactContactContact MoreTextOhNo"+i);
```

*with space here to break the line* **^**

Comment: Thank you but what I'm looking for is that when the text name comes at the end of the div , it goes inline, I don't want to put break in the names